# Facepile shows a white patch when user not connected to facebook

Tags: c#, facebook

I have a scenario.: My website contains list of Agents. Each agent is having his/her own website. So when any agent enters into my website and searches then he will get list of agent details along with their basic information. Here I want to display people who liked the individual websites using facebook. 
Using facepile I had acheived this but facepile works only if the user is logged-in to the facebook. This scenario is also fine with me. But my requirement is I am able to see a white patch of space between the results when user is not connected to FB. I want to make this patch to be visible false when not connected to FB.

I am not using any application or App ID, I just used Iframe and url of agents facebook ID as href.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the broken facepile plugin, try using the like plugin as it does not exhibit this behaviour.